# Pass email address by session between two controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function registration()
{
    $data = array();
    $userData = array();

    if($this->input->post('regisSubmit')){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');

        $userData = array(
            'name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('name')),
            'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'phone' => strip_tags($this->input->post('phone'))
        );

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
            $insert = $this->user->insert($userData);
            if($insert){



                redirect('email');
            }else{
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Some problems occured, please try again.';
            }
        }
    }
    $data['user'] = $userData;
    //load the view
    $this->load->view('users/registration', $data);
}
```

This is a function of my registration controller. I wish to pass the email address to my another controller: send_email and use this code to send email to the user.

`$this->email->to('user_email');` I tried to use session function to pass the variable but failed. what should I do?

Comment: md5 is way too weak for hashing passwords. PHP has got a group of functions for dealing with the hashing of passwords

Comment: Look up password hash in the PHP docs. Never use md5. "'password'  => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options),"

Comment: Thanks for your guys helping. I will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**Note:** *you have to load `session` library in `autoload.php` if not loaded and also avoid `md5` to encrypt password, use `password_hash` instead*

Then have to create `email`  session before `redirect();`

Code structure should be like this

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
{      
  $insert = $this->user->insert($userData);
  if($insert)
  {
    $this->session->set_userdata('email',$userData['email']);
    redirect('email');   
  }else
  {
    $data['error_msg'] = 'Some problems occured, please try again.';
  }
}
```

Use session in `send_email` method like this

```
public function send_email()
{
   $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
   echo $email;
   /* 
    $this->email->to($email);
    do whatever u want
   */
 }
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for your helping, and It is really useful. I was working on my another project so forget to check the answer.